# How add modul to node.js

Tags: node.js, formidable

I want to ask how can I add modul to node.js. I me I've installed node.js and want to create a simple form for uploading  image. When I require a 'formidable' module and create a new object from it, i get an error 'cannot find the modul formidabe' .

Answer (score 0):

Via npm (the node package manager), try this from your command line:

```
npm install formidable
```

as explained in the [docs](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable). After that it should work.